# Return response as array instead of as an object in Contentful

Tags: response, contentful

I need to receive an array of objects as response from Contentful API. I tried to use "?select=fields" but that again returns an object with property items which is an array. I want to get the items array directly as a response is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with the Contentful API. To my knowledge, it always returns `items`.